# Table has a list of forms received from client. I need to find all clients who have not submitted form C

Tags: sql

Table has a list of forms received from Client.  I need to find all client who have not submitted Form C

```
ClientID     Form ID    DateReceived
1               A       7/1/16
1               B       7/2/16
1               C       7/3/16
2               A       8/1/16
2               B       8/1/16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select clientid
from t
group by clientid
having sum(case when formid = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Alternatively, if I assume you have a `clients` table, a more natural way to write the query is:

```
select c.*
from clients c
where not exists (select 1
                  from clientforms cf
                  where cf.clientid = c.clientid and cf.formid = 'C'
                 );
```

This is a better approach because it returns clients who have not submitted any forms at all.